# How to serialize a XML without unnecessary spaces and line breaks? (.NET)

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization

I'm using [XmlSerializer.Serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize.aspx), and it produces line breaks and unnecessary spaces. How to avoid it?

Comment: Old, but I believe the difference is whether you are using a XmlWriter or a TextWriter.  In my experience, XmlWriter defaults to no formatting.  This makes sense, because it knows it is writing a document where the formatting does not matter, whereas a text writer is writing straight text.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the overload accepting an `XmlWriter`, and configure the given `XmlWriter` with an [`XmlWriterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) instance?

`XmlWriterSettings` allows you to control the application of line breaks and indentation.

```csharp
void Serialize(Object o)
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = false;
    settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;
    //settings.OtherProperties = values;

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(CreateStream(), settings))
    {
        _serializer.Serialize(writer, o);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to switch the parameters around like this: `_serializer.Serialize(writer, o);`. Great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's interesting, I thought there was no formatting by default. I just tried the following and got no formatting:

```csharp
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    System.Text.Encoding encoding;
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
    {
        if (writer == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("writer is null");
        }

        encoding = writer.Settings.Encoding;
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        ser.Serialize(writer, obj);
    }

    stream.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding, true))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

in a sample run, it returned the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><obj xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><childOne /><childTwo /><text>text1</text><text>text2</text></obj>
```

Comment: Such an inconsistency should be reported to Microsoft. A method cannot behave in different ways. It's CultureInfo dependent? Or it's a .NET Version/Service Pack? I don't know yet.

Comment: If you get a chance, run the code I posted. I'm running .NET 3.5 SP1. Let's see what the real difference is.

Comment: Your code had no whitespace in .net 4.5. But my other implementation did, and that was passing a StringWriter instance into the Serialize call's first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Please also check if serialized classes contain members of XML-type (like XmlElement). I used Xsd2Code tool to generate classes from XSD and (in very special case) it has created a member of type XmlElement. During serialization this member had its own formatting (identation to be exact). Even if I had turned on (or off) XmlSerializer indentation it had no affect on the XmlElement member.